# Animating different markers API V3 Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have got some markers in my map and i wanted to animate one or another marker depending in which one i made "click". But the animation just work with the last marker that i create and not with the others ones.
I tried make the marker as an array but is the same problem.
Here is the Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var marker = null;
    var address = null;
    var altura = null;

function codeAddress() {
  altura = document.getElementById('altura').value;
  address = document.getElementById('address').value + ' ' + altura ;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    // Marker
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: document.getElementById('icono').value,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
      });
    // Animating Listener
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
    } else {
      alert('Error: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep references to all the markers that you want to animate, then set the animation on the correct one.  The code you posted only has one marker.

One way of solving your problem is with function closure:

```
function createMarker(latlng, address, icon){
    // Marker
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          position: latlng,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
      });
    // Animating Listener
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
          marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
          marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
      });
}
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_geocodeAnimateOnClick.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
It is making the same problem.
I made a new marker and when i click it is okay, but when i make a new one i can't do the action with the previous. Here is the new  adapted Code: http://pastebin.com/Puie9sW7

Comment: Your code is different from that posted above. It is missing the "var" before the marker, that still leaves only one marker.

Comment: Is perfect! Thanks you again geocodezip, this is the second time that you save me. Thank you very much.